# Update MySQL table if non-primary key column is duplicate, insert otherwise?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table with an autoincremented primary key, and a column for a person's name, and some data.

Is there a MySQL query where I can insert a new row if the name of the person is unique, but if it's a duplicate name, then I would update that row?

I.e.

```
ID, Name,        Data
1 , Michael,     x
2 , Stephen,     y
3 , Christopher, z
```

If I were to add a "Michael" to the database with "qq" data, I would want the database to look like this:

```
ID, Name,        Data
1 , Michael,     qq
2 , Stephen,     y
3 , Christopher, z
```

If I were to add "John" with "zz" data, the database would look like this:

```
ID, Name,        Data
1 , Michael,     x
2 , Stephen,     y
3 , Christopher, z
4 , John,        zz
```

I know of the command, ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, but I only want to update if the name is the same, not if the primary key is the same.

Comment: had you heard about stored procedures ? they make this very simple http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx

Comment: Just add an `UNIQUE INDEX` on `Name`, nothing big to lose.

Comment: Thank you for the link legendinmaking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a `UNIQUE` index on `Name`. `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will then work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a stored procedure and simply call it in your query code

> **PROCEDURE:**

```
   DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS InsUpdTable $$
        CREATE PROCEDURE InsUpdTable
        (
          IN _name VARCHAR(45),
          IN _data VARCHAR(45)
        )
        BEGIN
        if exists (select ID from mytable where name = _name)
        Then
          update mytable set data = _data where name=_name;
        else
          insert into mytable(name, data) values(_name, _data);
        END IF;
        END $$
        DELIMITER ;
```

> **Query:**

```
call InsUpdTable('John','zzz')
```